# SfListView perfectly works in UWP but it crash in Android

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am using Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView in my code. By loading the program in Uwp, it works fine and listView display items properly, but in Android, get crash.
Does anybody know the problem?

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="MatchParent">
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
     <sfListView:SfListView ItemsSource="{Binding serviceItems}" 
                 ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" >                    
         <sfListView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <FlexLayout Direction="Column" 
                                         x:DataType="model:ServiceItems">
                  <Image Source="{Binding Images}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                               FlexLayout.Basis="15%" />
                </FlexLayout>
             </DataTemplate>
         </sfListView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
     </sfListView:SfListView>
</StackLayout>
```

> i got the error : 
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ServiceItemsView (ReflectionActivator), Services = [ServiceItems (System.Object)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'ServiceItemsView'. ---> VTable setup of type Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView failed (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) --->

Comment: As mentioned in error message, there is an inner exception, but you've not put the entire data here. instead of using exception.Message, use exception.ToString() You might be able to find a problem yourself too!

Answer (score 1):

It would be fixed by upgrading your application to Xamarin stable version. For example, 3.4.0.1039999 is the stable version in the Xamarin 3.4 update.